# Not Able To Create Pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I followed the official [Kubernetes installation guide](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_manual_config.html) to install Kubernetes on Fedora 22 severs. Everything works out for me during the installation .

After the installation. I could see all my nodes are up-running and connected to the master. However, it kept failing while I try to create a simple pod, according to the [101 guide](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/walkthrough/README.html).

```
$ create -f pod-nginx.yaml
```

Error from server: error when creating "pod-nginx.yaml": Pod "nginx" is forbidden: no API token found for service account default/default, retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account

Do I need to create a API token? If yes, how?

I googled the issue, but without any helpful results. Looks like I am the only one hit into the issue on this planet.

Dose anyone have ideas on this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The ServiceAccount admission controller prevents pods from being created until their service account in their namespace is initialized.

If the controller-manager is started with the appropriate arguments, it will automatically populate namespaces with a default service account, and auto-create the API token for that service account.

It looks like that guide needs to be updated with the information from this comment:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/11355#issuecomment-127378691

Answer (score 14):

1. ```
   openssl genrsa -out /tmp/serviceaccount.key 2048
   ```
2. ```
   vim /etc/kubernetes/apiserver:
   KUBE_API_ARGS="--service_account_key_file=/tmp/serviceaccount.key"
   ```
3. ```
   vim /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager
   KUBE_CONTROLLER_MANAGER_ARGS="--service_account_private_key_file=/tmp/serviceaccount.key"
   systemctl restart kube-controller-manager.service
   ```

Comment: Where do I need to do that? On the Master/Head server or on all Nodes/Minions? I followed these steps on the master, but it does not change anything (Kubernetes 1.2.0 on Debian Jessie (8.3)). I still get that error message.

Comment: Not sure what environment these commands are for, but in my case I needed to have a look at the /etc/default/kube-controller-manager and /etc/default/kube-apiserver files (init.d based service startup) to specify the service_account_(private_)key_file.

Comment: why did you create the key under `/tmp` directory?